# Is it possible to avoid mail-related packages?

Tags: email

On GNU Linux (Ubuntu, Mint, ...), is it possible to install emacs avoiding the installation of mutt, postfix, mailutils and other mail-related packages?

Answer (score 3):

Emacs doesn’t depend on any of those things, so it should be. However, Emacs doesn’t make the packages, the distro does. If Ubuntu’s Emacs package has dependencies that don’t make sense then you need to file a bug report with Ubuntu, not with Emacs. In the mean time you can download binaries directly [from the GNU project](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), or you can install directly [from the source](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=emacs).